# What is the difference between Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] and Request.UserHostAddress?

Tags: asp.net, ip-address, httprequest

What is the difference between `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and `Request.UserHostAddress`?

Are either of these variables considered unreliable with respect to IP Address spoofing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Request.UserHostAddress and Request.ServerVariables\["REMOTE\_ADDR"\].ToString()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994582/what-is-the-difference-between-request-userhostaddress-and-request-servervariabl)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim considering I asked this question in June 2011 and that question was asked in December 2012 I don't think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The .ServerVariables is provided for compatibility with the old ASP method for getting that information.  Most of the information provided through that is now provided through separate properties.

Comment: Do you know anything about the reliablity of these variables?  Is it easy for someone to 'fake' their IP Address?

Comment: I don't know about faking an IP address.  I know things like the referrerUrl can be faked.  It is the same facility as the old ServerVariables just remapped so if you could fake it before, I'm sure you can still mess with the values.

Answer (score 6):

They are the same, `ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` was provided only for backwards compatibility with older Classic Asp codebases. You should prefer using `Request.UserHostAddress`.