# how to get the client ip address through the balancer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

there is such situation: i have the server my.qwe (192.168.0.1) which addresses to balancer 192.168.0.2 which throws the client on 192.168.0.3 or 192.168.0.4. I make a request from the machine 192.168.0.5. Question: how to get the ip address of my machine. Note: I used

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_COMING_FROM"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_VIA"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_COMING_FROM"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FROM"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["CLIENT_IP"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["FORWARDED"]
```

gives out either the empty string or the ip address of the balancer 192.168.0.2, what should I do ???

Comment: Why don't you implement some code that dumps out all the headers on the request, and then you can easily see which one contains the client's real IP?

Answer (score -1):

You can use either:

```
Request.UserHostAddress
```

Or:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Both should work. You can find more info about that here:

[What is the difference between Request.UserHostAddress and Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13994582/9233618)

Comment: I used it, but it returned ip adress of balancer 192.168.0.2, i need 192.168.0.5